# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE doesn't find the data

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a problem with REGEXP_LIKE in ORACLE. In the table CLOB column there is following data:

```
some text 1{000000}some text 2{000000}some text 3{000error001}some text 4{000001}
```

The key is to find {000error001} which contains invalid data. I tried following regular expression which is working fine in online regex testing tools:

```
\{(?:.(?!\}))+\D+(?:.*?)\}
```

but when it's added to select statement:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('some text 1{000000}some text 2{000000}some text 3{000error001}some text 4{000001}', '\{(?:.(?!\}))+\D+(?:.*?)\}') FROM DUAL;
```

it's not working at all (returns 0).

Any ideas why?

I tried with multiple combinations of the regex pattern, but only this one showing correct results, unfortunately only in the regexp online testing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to find strings between curly braces that contain at least one non-digit char you can use

```
\{[0-9]*[^0-9{}][^{}]*}
```

*Details*:

- `\{`  - a `{` char
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `[^0-9{}]` - a char other than a digit and `{`/`}`
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2l8pj3/1).

Actually, you can even use `\{[^{}]*[^0-9{}][^{}]*}`, but since valid strings only contain digits inside curly braces, the expression above is fine and even more efficient.

Comment: Already tested. Thanks man, it works like a charm :) I was fixed on my solution and have lost sight on different approach.

Comment: Hi. One more request for help. I found in my code something like this:

{00text10000}text2{00text30000}guid="{AF67319E-8291-45B0-925C-904192E1CA9B}"

Regular expression {[^{}][^0-9{}][^{}]} works fine, but I don't want to capture

{AF67319E-8291-45B0-925C-904192E1CA9B}

because this value in the brackets is correct if before exists guid=". Any help with this one?

Comment: @ŁukaszJesionek You can't do this  with Oracle regex, since it does not support lookbehinds. Here, I understand you want `(?<!guid="){[^{}]*[^0-9{}][^{}]*}` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwkpNm/1)), but `(?<!)` is not supported in your environment. I do not know how to work around this.